# Asynchronous File Stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an async. in the WriteText method so the `sourceStream` will use async., but I get an error at `useAsync`

```
async private Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)
        {
            byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096, useAsync))
            {
              await  sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `useAsync` for `useAsync:true`